# ViewResult.ViewName returns empty on UnitTest

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, unit-testing, tdd

I see there are a lot of questions about this same topic, but since they are all from 2008 - 2011, I'd say there's a chance this might be an official way to do this **without external libraries/extensions.**

So the issue is when running my test cases, the `ViewName` comes empty:

```
// Act
ViewResult result = await Controller.Create(model) as ViewResult;

// Assert
Assert.AreEqual("Create", result.ViewName);
```

Any official way to deal with this? or maybe I can test some other property?

Answer (score 0):

If your Controller Method does just

```
return View();
```

without a view name parameter value given, you will not have the name of the view in the `ViewName` property. For Unit Testing Controllers read: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff847525(v=vs.100).aspx

How to create a controller with `ControllerContext`:

```
HomeController controller = new HomeController(repository);

controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext()
{
    Controller = controller,
    RequestContext = new RequestContext(new MockHttpContext(), new RouteData())
};
```

With:

```
private class MockHttpContext : HttpContextBase {
    private readonly IPrincipal _user = new GenericPrincipal(
             new GenericIdentity("someUser"), null /* roles */);

    public override IPrincipal User {
        get {
            return _user;
        }
        set {
            base.User = value;
        }
    }
}
```